# How are coordinates chosen in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

disclaimer: this is my first time asking a question.

In general relativity, I have been told that everything stems from the coordinates we have and that from these, we can derive the metric and, thus, everything else about the system such as the geodesic equations. I was also told that this means that there are proper coordinates to use in general relativity, we cannot use any coordinate system we like. What I want to know is how we know what coordinates to use for a given situation? For example (oversimplified for sure), if we have polar coordinates, we can derive a metric and geodesic equations of motion for these, but how do we know that the space we are describing is correctly described by polar coordinates?

update, I have asked my professor for clarification on what he meant, and this is what he said:
"1. You can always pick any four vectors, let's call them t, a, b, c to be the basis of your coordinate system.
2. Once you've made this choice, the dot product between these two vectors is NOT arbitrary, but is the corresponding value in the metric g_uv which, as we say, is related to the stress-energy tensor through Einstein's Equations.
3. The way I think of it, that means that you practically can't pick any coordinate system.  For example, if you pick "spherical coordinates" outside a mass M (the Schwarzschild Metric), it is NOT normal spherical coordinates:  r dot r is NOT equal to 1 as you would think from the equations defining this coordinate system, but has to be g_rr in that metric. Therefore, coordinates are not really as arbitrary as the poster implied they are -- yes, you can pick whatever basis you want, but the relationship between those basis vectors is given entirely by the metric g_uv derived for the stress-energy tensor T_uv."

my confusion is, I think, as follows: take where it says the dot product is not necessarily what we would expect, so these aren't spherical coordinates in the traditional sense. so it seems there is something imposed that I'm not sure where it comes from, and I think this imposition is at the heart of my confusion.

Comment: "[...] we cannot use any coordinate system we like." This is the diametric opposite of the truth. The entire point of incorporating [general covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance) into GR is precisely to allow for arbitrary (well-defined) choices of coordinate. Perhaps you are misinterpreting your source - can you provide a reference or more direct quote?

Comment: i'll edit my post to include the exact quote from my professor since it's too long to paste here in the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if the source was saying exactly what General Relativity is *not*. As pointed out in the comments, General Relativity a is covariant (coordinate *independent*) theory. In other words, it is formulated geometrically in terms of invariant geometric objects (tensors), and coordinates are essentially just a tool in order to compute calculations. They say nothing about the physical system itself.

That being said, there is often a 'canonical' choice of coordinates: a chosen set of coordinates that mirror the symmetry of the problem you're trying to solve. So if you're dealing with spherical symmetry, it may be more natural to use polar coordinates (and this may make the equations take a simpler form). Certain coordinates may also make the symmetries, known as isometries in GR, more obvious. But this does not mean there are 'proper coordinates' as any choice is equally valid. This freedom to choose your coordinate system is sometimes seen as intrinsically linked with GR$^1$. Studying how to find exact solutions in GR is a huge area of research, and a lot of effort goes into adapting useful coordinate systems for this purpose, but this is purely for utility and says nothing about which coordinate description is more correct$^2$.

---

$^1$I should also clarify that this coordinate independence is true for all physical theories (if they're formulated correctly), not just General Relativity. When we do physics, make measurements, etc, the choice of coordinates we choose to use do not at all impact what's actually happening. What is perhaps less trivial about GR, that sets it apart from other theories like Special Relativity, is that there's no preferred forumulation that lends itself to a particular set of coordinates. This is really a consequence of the more important property of being *background independent*.

$^2$ There's also the other caveat that different coordinate charts may be defined in different neighbourhoods/regions, which means some may be be better adapted to certain spacetimes, given what you're trying calculate. Again, this is a practical issue.

On covariance:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_covariance

Comment: this makes sense overall, but it doesn't reconcile the confusion I am having. so I added an exact quote to my post and it seems like there is still something outside of our choosing that is restricted in general relativity? for example where it says the dot product is not necessarily what we would expect, so these aren't spherical coordinates in the traditional sense. so it seems there is something imposed that I'm not sure where it comes from.

Comment: This probably comes down to how much GR/differential geometry you know, but really you can do GR *without* needing coordinates at all. They don't play a role. However, as I said, it's handy for calculations, so you pick some coordinate charts and they form an atlas on your manifold. You're completely free to go to any other coordinate chart you like: any smooth continuous transformation is acceptable (this is the diffeomorphism group $\rm{diff}\mathcal{M}$). All these transformations *do not* change the metric, so of course you're not going to get the Euclidean metric for a general spacetime.

Comment: When you think about GR you really want to move away from the vector calculus you've learnt in Euclidean space because the analogies will no longer work. The coordinates do not have the intrinsic meaning you're used to. Maybe your confusion comes from that fact? And that you can work in *any* coordinates (meaning you start with your metric representing the physical spacetime, and you can make **any** coordinate transformation $(t,x,y,z) \rightarrow (u,v,\theta,\phi)$ with some formula for these transformation) but you have to work out what these coordinates physically mean.

Comment: i think that helps. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Coordinate system is just a frame of reference in which you are studying the motion and relativity over it . And you are free to choose the frame of reference and so the coordinate system . For clarity please quote the written text which suggests to use a certain coordinate system.

Comment: While this is interesting, it isn't a answer to the question, so its place is in the comment section. Remember that this is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: @Miyase I am new on this platform so don't now much more about qna or forum but will be interesting if there is any proper coordinate system is present or not so that why I asked him to quote the text

Comment: You're supposed to have read the rules of the site after registration. Your enquiry is legitimate, but the place to write it is the comment section. Thanks for your next contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason to choose a coordinate system in general relativity is convenience. For "convenience" you can read ease of calculation, ease of understanding, or similar ideas.

There is a concept called ["proper time."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) This is the time that would be experienced by a test particle following the path being studied. An astronaut taking a journey, for example, experiences proper time as the duration of the trip.

There are "natural" ways to define the time coordinate. In the book ["Gravitation"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691177791) by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler, there is an explanation of the "usual" way to define time. Time is defined so that motion looks simple. Basically, that means that proper time and coordinate time have a relationship. And objects moving without acceleration have smooth paths in space-time.

However, general relativity is usually written in a form such that the coordinates are not required to have any particular form.  Many of the results of GR are such that they don't depend on the coordinate system. Though they may require the units of measurement to be explicitly stated.

For example: Suppose you were calculating the advance of the perihelion of Mercury, a famous result derived by Einstein. You could do this using any convenient coordinate basis. Then you would report the results as so many arc seconds per century. Notice that the result does not depend on the coordinate system you used to do the calculations. The usual way this result is presented is in terms of the Schwarzschild exterior solution written in terms of $(t, r, \theta, \phi)$, spherical polar coords. This is because the system is taken to be spherically symmetric, and the equations are much simpler in that case. However, nothing (except the desire for that easier calculation) is stopping you from using another coordinate system.

Indeed, one way to check that you have done such calculations correctly is to do them in another basis and check that you get the same result at the end. (Though I have never seen anybody do the perihelion advance in anything other than spherical polar coords. It would probably be pretty tough in $(t, x, y, z)$.)

In many situations a change of coordinates will make a result easier to understand.  For example, [Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) have useful properties in understanding a black hole. In particular, the usual coordinates for a Schwarschild black hole have a singularity at the horizon. But the K-S coords are well behaved at the horizon.  There will be such considerations in cosmological solutions as well.

To summarize: You may select different coordinate systems for different purposes, primarily based on convenience.